# docker container automcatically deleted

Tags: dockerfile

Am trying to run Dgoss(server validation tool) on my Docker image  but It's not working. Container is getting deleted automatically. Please help me !!

snippet of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:4-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV "production"
ENV PORT 8079

RUN addgroup mygroup && adduser -D -G mygroup myuser && mkdir -p 
/usr/src/app && chown -R myuser /usr/src/app

# Prepare app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
COPY yarn.lock /usr/src/app/
RUN chown myuser /usr/src/app/yarn.lock

USER myuser
RUN yarn install

COPY . /usr/src/app

# Start the app
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/npm", "start"]
```

Command:

```
> dgoss edit test-1

Error:
INFO: Starting docker container
INFO: Container ID: 4a631969
INFO: Run goss add/autoadd to add resources
/goss $ INFO: Deleting container
```

Comment: Having the same problem - docker container get deleted automatically every once in a while